# Upgrading to TFS 2018

Tags: upgrade, sql-server-2017

I am planning to upgrade this instance to TFS 2018

- Windows Server 2012
- SQL Server 2014
- TFS 2017 Update 2

Per the requirements [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/requirements), TFS 2017 Update 2 doesn't support SQL 2017, so it seems the only valid upgrade sequence is:

1. Upgrade SQL 2014 to 2016
2. Upgrade TFS 2017 to 2018
3. Upgrade SQL 2016 to 2017

Is this correct? I do want to use the latest version of SQL hence step 3.

Would it be possible to Upgrade SQL all the way to 2017 first and then upgrade to TFS 2018 instead of going though intermediary 2016 upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can uninstall TFS 2017, upgrade SQL server, install TFS2018 and then let the TFS 2018 installer upgrade the database.

Answer (score 0):

We had like the same scenario.
What we did: We had new Servers. There we directly installed latest SQL.
Than we copied the mdf´s to the server. (After stopping old TFS and detached sql, than attach on new one)
Than installed TFS - TFS is doing all the upgrades it has to.

We did this scenario like 4 times, and it always worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference I had is that we were on Windows Server 2008 R2. Before moving to TFS 2018 Update 2, I had to make the following steps on the involved environments:

1. In-place upgrade to Windows Server 2012 R2
2. In-place upgrade SQL 2014 SP2 to 2016 SP2
3. Upgrade from TFS 2017 to 2018 Update 2

There isn't required to upgrade your SQL to 2017 if you do not want to. It would work just fine on SQL Server 2016 SP2